# Lucky number 7!

Tags: discussion

Lets keep up the good work - great questions. It's building up to be a great place!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the notice and the heads up! For the longer-term usefulness of meta, I'm going to close this to keep this area information rich and relevant. Thanks.